# Se me duplica el dato guardado en un array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Se me duplica el dato guardado en el HTML no se duplica lo muestra como debe de ser pero en la consola si los duplica si pongo 1 sale 1 en la lista del html pero en la consola sale 1 pero si vuelvo aponer otro 1 y ya se me duplica hay dos numeros 1  en consola pero en la lista del html hay dos como debe de ser.

Y en la suma sale 011 ya que no suma y solo los junta (el valor que ingrese y el duplicado) algo asi arrayinput[i] + arrayinput[i] mas lo que vale la variable que es 0 el resultado sale 011 y asi sucesivamente si voy agregando numeros

```js
const agregarVar = document.querySelector('#añadir');
const inputAgregarVar = document.querySelector('#inputventa');


var arrayinput = [];

function listado() {
    if ((inputAgregarVar.value == '')) {
        alert('vacio');
        inputventa.focus();
    } else
    if (inputAgregarVar.value > 0) {
        arrayinput.push(inputAgregarVar.value)
        inputAgregarVar.value = '';
        inputAgregarVar.focus();
        mostrar(arrayinput);
        sumar(arrayinput);
    } else
        alert('Debe de ser positivo');
    inputventa.focus();
};

function mostrar(arrayinput) {
    var listaUlVar = document.querySelector('#lista');
    listaUlVar.innerHTML = '';
    for (i of arrayinput) {
        var listaLi = document.createElement('li');
        listaUlVar.appendChild(listaLi);
        listaLi.innerText = i;
        console.log(i);
    }
}

function sumar(arrayinput) {
    var suma = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayinput.length; i++) {
        suma += arrayinput[i];
    }
    console.log("suma total", suma);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> $ </p> <input type="text" class="inputcolor " name="" id="inputventa">
    <button type="submit" id="añadir" class="btn btn-color ">Añadir</button>
    <button type="submit" id="Terminar" class="btn btn-color">Terminar</button>
                        <td>
                            <ul id="lista"> </ul>
                        </td>
                        <script>
$("#añadir").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  listado();
}); 
</script>

<script>
$("#Terminar").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
sumar();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Saludos. Lo que ocurre es que tu sabes es un número lo que se ingresa; sin embargo el `input` lo que tiene es texto; por tanto lo que hace es concatenar texto; lo que debes hacer es convertir a entero o flotante (según el tipo de numero que corresponda al momento de usar el `push`  ( parseFloat: https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_parsefloat.asp -- partInt: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) `arrayinput.push(parseFloat(inputAgregarVar.value));` o `arrayinput.push(parseInt(inputAgregarVar.value));` (no olvides finalizar cada instrucción *;*).

Comment: hooo ok voy a intentarlo gracias

Comment: por eso se duplica  y por que?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por así decirlo; los `input` contienen texto; tal que lo que agregas al array en el push realmente es texto, en tu función `suma` lo que haces es concatenar texto, no propiamente la operación de suma.

```js
const agregarVar = document.querySelector('#añadir');
const inputAgregarVar = document.querySelector('#inputventa');


var arrayinput = [];

function listado() {
    if ((inputAgregarVar.value == '')) {
        alert('vacio');
        inputventa.focus();
    } else
    if (inputAgregarVar.value > 0) {
        // Aqui puedes modificar para convertir a numero
        arrayinput.push(parseFloat(inputAgregarVar.value)); // Se convierte a numero y se agrega
        // arrayinput.push(inputAgregarVar.value); // Aqui agregas texto
        inputAgregarVar.value = '';
        inputAgregarVar.focus();
        mostrar(arrayinput);
        sumar(arrayinput);
    } else
        alert('Debe de ser positivo');
    inputventa.focus();
};

function mostrar(arrayinput) {
    var listaUlVar = document.querySelector('#lista');
    listaUlVar.innerHTML = '';
    for (i of arrayinput) {
        var listaLi = document.createElement('li');
        listaUlVar.appendChild(listaLi);
        listaLi.innerText = i;
        console.log(i);
    }
}

function sumar(arrayinput) {
    var suma = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayinput.length; i++) {
        // Aqui puede igual hacer la conversión, según prefieras.
        suma +=parseFloat(arrayinput[i]); // Convertimos a numero antes de sumar
        //suma +=arrayinput[i]; // Si ya esta convertido lo sumara, sino aún es texto concatenara.
    }
    console.log("suma total", suma);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> $ </p> <input type="number" class="inputcolor " name="" id="inputventa">
    <button type="submit" id="añadir" class="btn btn-color ">Añadir</button>
    <button type="submit" id="Terminar" class="btn btn-color">Terminar</button>
                        <td>
                            <ul id="lista"> </ul>
                        </td>
                        <script>
$("#añadir").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  listado();
}); 
</script>

<script>
$("#Terminar").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
sumar();
});
</script>
```

Comment: gracias y en caso que lo quiera guardar en mysql lo tengo que mandar por medio de ajax?

Comment: @BryanRL envia los datos tal cual; ya sea como texto o como numero, al momento de realizar el guardado se hace en automático la conversión; desde luego cuidando que los valores que se reciban corresponda a un dato válido para el campo donde se guardaran.

Answer (score 2):

Se te duplica el dato porque en vez de sumar estas concatenando.

```js
const agregarVar = document.querySelector('#añadir');
const inputAgregarVar = document.querySelector('#inputventa');

var arrayinput = [];

function listado() {
/* inputAgregarVar.value es de tipo string,
 podes chequear de la siguiente manera,
 fijate en la siguiente linea*/
console.log(typeof inputAgregarVar.value)
/* por este motivo en vez de realizar la suma
lo unico que esta haciendo es concatenar.
 Estaria haciendo esto:*/
let letraA = "a"
let restoDelAbecedario = "bcdefg...."
console.log( letraA + restoDelAbecedario)
/*Una forma de solucionar esto es asi convertirlo a int antes de que agregues a tu array.*/
let inputConvertidoAEntero = Number.parseInt(inputAgregarVar.value, 10); //inputAgregarVar.value convertimos a int
   if ((inputAgregarVar.value == '')) {
        alert('vacio');
        inputventa.focus();
    } else
       if (inputConvertidoAEntero > 0) {
          arrayinput.push(inputConvertidoAEntero)
          inputAgregarVar.value = '';
          inputAgregarVar.focus();
          mostrar(arrayinput);
          sumar(arrayinput);
    } else
        alert('Debe de ser positivo');
        inputventa.focus();
};

function mostrar(arrayinput) {
    var listaUlVar = document.querySelector('#lista');
    listaUlVar.innerHTML = '';
    for (i of arrayinput) {
        var listaLi = document.createElement('li');
        listaUlVar.appendChild(listaLi);
        listaLi.innerText = i;
        console.log(i);
    }
}

function sumar(arrayinput) {
    var suma = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayinput.length; i++) {
        suma += arrayinput[i];
    }
    console.log("suma total", suma);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> $ </p>
<input type="text" class="inputcolor " name="" id="inputventa">
<button type="submit" id="añadir" class="btn btn-color ">Añadir</button>
<button type="submit" id="Terminar" class="btn btn-color">Terminar</button>
<td>
   <ul id="lista"> </ul>
</td>
<script>
$("#añadir").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  listado();
}); 
</script>

<script>
$("#Terminar").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
sumar();
});
</script>
```

Tu inputAgregarVar.value es de tipo string por ese motivo en vez de sumar esta concatenando. Tambien te aconsejo que sigas las convenciones para nombrar variables en JavaScript.
Las variables const deberian de ser todas en mayusculas:

```
//const agregarVar = document.querySelector('#añadir');
const AGREGAR_VAR = document.querySelector('#añadir');
```

Te dejo un link para leer mas sobre las [convenciones](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-naming-conventions-dos-and-don-ts-99c0e2fdd78a/)

Saludos!

Comment: gracias , y como le haría si lo quiero guardar en mysql osea el arreglo y el total cuando le de en guardar ?

Comment: @BryanRL bueno me imagino que ya tenes una base de datos. Ahora lo que quiero saber es si ya tenes algo de código para conectar a tu base de datos?

Comment: Si anteriormente mandé por medio de Ajax y los mandaba a php ahí los recibia los inserta a con PDO .

Comment: Pero con esta no tengo idea de cómo mandarlo

Comment: Años atras JavaScript era considerado un lenguaje Client-Side. Por fortuna eso cambio ahora. Asi que para poder conectarlo a Mysql podemos utilizar como puente NodeJS (que seria nuestro lenguaje JavaScript Server-Side). Otra opcion seria usar Ruby. Cual es tu environment Windows? Mac? Linux?

Comment: En fin una vez que tenes configurado tu Back-end podes
hacer un fetch post para poder hacer el insert en tu base de datos. Algo asi se veria tu codigo [enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/6t1b4n2f/)